# Is nested modeling the right way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a new project. Where I allow a user to register on the website. What I would like to accomplish is that in the form they use to register, they also add a company name. This should be for another model called company.

The person that creates this will be an admin. For others to be an employee of the company, the admin will have to invite them.

I'm wondering how to set this up. Should I:

- Create a nested model on the user registration for a model called company where they add their company name on the form.
- The user should then have an update_attribute where admin becomes true.

Also how should the association be, a user belongs to a company, and a company has_many users?

Answer (score 0):

Right, your question is rather extensive but I can nudge you in the right direction in regards to creation a form with fields that connect to multiple model objects. The key is in using fields_for helper...

To do this, I would do the following..

**company.rb**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
end
```

**companies_controller.rb**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
   def new
    @company = Company.new
    @user = User.new
   end

   def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, companies_attributes:[:name])
   end
end
```

**views/companies/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= fields_for @company do |u| %>

    <p>
        <%= u.label :name %><br />
        <%= u.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <% end %>

    <p>
        <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

You can easily take it from here and make it more complex as you like it.

Comment: shouldn't it be that a company has_many users, and a user belongs_to company.  As a company can have several people connected to it (employees) and then the separation would be to make the users have an admin boolean to see who's the admin of that company?

Comment: you are right, my bad. updated and should work as you need it to

Comment: Ok, in regards to admin privileges, I suggest you look into authorization with cancan.